# How to determine accuracy from RMSLE?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science

In my machine Learning model, I have used **RMSLE** and through Gradient boost Regression I have got the value of `RMSLE = 0.123657`

How to interpret this value in terms of accuracy in R or python?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56658/how-do-you-interpret-rmsle-root-mean-squared-logarithmic-error

Comment: @TimH I saw that post earlier and I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you shouldn't.

Accuracy and REMSLE are metrics to measure different types of models, where **accuracy** is used to measure the overall performance of a **classification model** and **RMSLE** is used to measure the error from a **regression model**.

Just for some clarification, regression models usually have a continuous variable as output, so is better to evaluate it calculating the distance between the predicted and real values, instead of accuracy, with gives you a binary output(if your model nailed it or not).

Comment: Okay, So, is that correct to say that when the RMSLE is low, does it means that the accuracy is high?

Comment: Exactly Prakash, since RMSLE is a calculation of the distance between real and estimated values, if the RMSLE is low, it means the estimated values are really close from the right values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Higher the RMSLE - the closer the predicted values to the actual values. And that's a general aim - To get closer to actual values. However, it's not directly linked to accuracy. You should better check on R-squared.